# Php QR Code library not working?

Tags: php

I got it to display with text but when i pass it into

```
function getQRcode($qr){

    include 'application/views/inc/qrcode.php';

    $this->view->qrcode = QRcode::png($qr);
    $this->view->render('user/qrcode');
}
```

It works fine but when this symbol '%' shows up in $qr variable it just wont work why is this ??

php qr code library: http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you're showing isn't particularly relevant as it doesn't show how you process the variable before you use it, nor the significant part(s) of the library.

At a guess you're passing in the value using GET/POST and aren't properly url-encoding the string. `%` is used for special sequences eg `%20` represents a space.

A list of characters that need to be encoded is [available here](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm).

Try replacing your `%` with `%25`.

For future reference, an online encoder/decoder can be found at http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Comment: sorry im stupid i only noticed its using url-encoding.